# Customising parameters in SqlDataSource

Tags: database

I am very new to Sharepoint and ASP and all of this so I suspect my question is really simple but I am confused.

I am using Sharepoint Designer 2007 and am not allowed to use code behind. The task was sold to me as a simple drag-and-drop exercise and that it would be straight-forward. I am now not so sure.

I created a `SqlDataSource` that has connected to my table without a problem and I can use a `Data View` to display that data without much problem. However I now need to do more specific things such as only selecting based on the currently logged in user and perform joins on the table and such.

So, I notice I can get information about the logged in user from an `asp:LoginName` but how do I pass this into a SQL query string to filter the displayed values? Or is there another way to pass data into SQL?

In the same way is it possible to pass information from drop down lists populated from a database into another dataview in order to filter based on that?

Comment: The datasource you are working with is a separate SQL database I suppose and not tables in a SharePoint content database?

Comment: @ThomasVochten That is correct, it is a separate SQL database that I connect to